# Как получить обозначение поля модели?

Tags: django, sqlite3

Как я могу поставить обозначение (типа `label` в формах) в модели, чтобы потом его можно было получить, как тут, например:

models:

```
class characterist_0001_pkModel(models.Model):
    a1 = models.CharField('Процессор. Процессор', label = 'Процессор', max_length= 40, null= True)
```

view:

```
# хочу получить: Процессор
characterist_0001_pkModel.a1.label
```